# Postgres query order by based on multiple fields

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table which has two columns, started_at and expired_at.

I need a sql query to get data first ordered on started_at and then all the expired entries.

Things to note i have expired_at date field. Entry will be expired based on current date, if date > expired_at then the entry is expired

Example

```
id  started_at  expired_at
1    11-03-19    12-03-19  
2    14-03-19    15-03-19  
3    15-03-19    02-05-19
```

Comment: `order by started_at, expired_at`?

Comment: this won't give expired entries in the last

Answer (score 0):

This SELECT first gives all the non-expired records, then the expired records:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
ORDER BY CASE WHEN expired_at > NOW() THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, started_at
```

Comment: @error-404 Did you try this out? Did it work for you?